# Can this foreach/if be simplified?

Tags: php, foreach

I wonder if I could do this easier. It checks if `$content` has a YouTube link inside it. If it does, then it runs a jQuery `$.getJson` to get the thumbnail of it and so...

But I found it very sloppy made by me, but how else should this be coded:

```
$isY = preg_match("#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=[0-9]/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+#", $content, $matches);

if($isY) {
  foreach(array_unique($matches) as $m) {
  ?>
    <script>
      $.getJSON (
        'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/<?php echo $m; ?>?v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=?',
        function(data) {
          youtubeFetchDataCallback(data, <?php echo $show['id']; ?>);
        }
      );
    </script>
  <?php
  }
}
```

Or is this okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the messiest part is the context switching. I would use string interpolation, and only open a single `<script>` tag:

```
<?php
if (preg_match("#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=[0-9]/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+#", $content, $matches)) {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">';

  foreach(array_unique($matches) as $m) {
    echo "
      $.getJSON (
        'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/$m?v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=?',
        function(data) {
          youtubeFetchDataCallback(data, $show[id]);
        }
      );
    ";
  }

  echo '</script>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To have something cleaner you could make your php code write a javascript array and then in javascript you can iterate over this array and get all the thumbnails.

If will be better than these multiple `<script>....</script>`

Something like (untested) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Videos = new Array(
<?
if($isY)
    foreach(array_unique($matches) as $m)
        echo '"'.$m.'",'
?>
);
for (v in Videos)
    $.getJSON( 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+v+'?v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=?', function(data) { 
youtubeFetchDataCallback(data, <?php echo $show['id']; ?>);
} );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this instead ... slightly cleaner:

```
$string = "#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=[0-9]/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+#";
        if(preg_match($string, $content, $matches);):
            foreach(array_unique($matches) as $m):
            ?>
            <script>
$.getJSON( 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/<?php echo $m; ?>?v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=?', function(data) { 
youtubeFetchDataCallback(data, <?php echo $show['id']; ?>);
} );
            </script>
            <?php
            endforeach;
        endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is already easier if you format it nicely:

```
if($isY){
    echo "<script>";

    foreach(array_unique($matches) as $m){
        echo "$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$m}v=2&alt=json-in-    script&callback=?', function(data) { 
youtubeFetchDataCallback(data,{$show['id']});";
        echo "} );";
    }

    echo "</script>";
}
```

You're right in not using a regex for this. The code is ok (no need to repeat the script-tag, though) - aim for maintainability.